# Android - Styles not applied to dialog fragment

Tags: android, styles, dialogfragment

I'm designing a filter dialog using Dialog Fragment. I applied styles for TextView's in the XML layout. I also set the style for Dialog Fragment using below code

Android Code :

```
setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.FullScreenDialogStyle);
```

Style XML:

```
<style name="FullScreenDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/pink</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/pink</item>

        <!-- Set this to true if you want Full Screen without status bar -->
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>

        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>

        <!-- This is important! Don't forget to set window background -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>

        <!-- Additionally if you want animations when dialog opening -->
        <!--<item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_up</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_down</item>-->

        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/FilterTextStyle</item>

    </style>

    <style name="FilterTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/tittle_text_black</item>
        <item name="fontPath">fonts/Lato-Medium.ttf</item>
    </style>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/customtoday"
        style="@style/FiltersSubText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:visibility="visible" />
```

But the styling is not applied to the views in the dialog.